# Continuous deployment from Visual Studio Team Services to Non-Windows Azure host

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, rackspace-cloud

This is a (very) long shot, but I was wondering if its possible to deploy from Visual Studio Team Services to a website that is hosted on Rackspace?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jon --

I have used TeamCity (by JetBeans) and CruiseControl.NET to deploy web sites. They both work with TFS (and Git).

ThoughtWorks has released "Go" into open source; it, too, allows builds and deployments.

I can only guess -- but would be confident -- that Visual Studio Team Services will work with any of those products.

-- Don